# nTrials must be be greater.... issue on conjoint design

Tags: r, analysis

I'm trying to create a list of conjoint cards using R.

I have followed the professor's introduction, with my own dataset, but I'm stuck with this issue, which I have no idea.

```
library(conjoint)
experiment<-expand.grid(
  ServiceRange = c("RA", "Active", "Passive","Basic"),
  IdentProce = c("high", "mid", "low"),
  Fee = c(1000,500,100),
  Firm = c("KorFin","KorComp","KorStrt", "ForComp")
) 
print(experiment)

design=caFactorialDesign(data=experiment, type="orthogonal")
print(design)
```

at the "design" line, I'm keep getting the following error message:

```
Error in optFederov(~., data, nTrials = i, approximate = FALSE, nRepeats = 50) :    
nTrials must not be greater than the number of rows in data
```

How do I address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you have 144 rows in `experiment`, but the `nTrials` mentioned in the error gets bigger than 144. This causes an error for `optFederov()`, which is called inside `caFactorialDesign()`.  The problem stems from the fact that your `Fee` column has relatively large values.

I'm not familiar with how the `conjoint` package is set up, but I can show you how to troubleshoot this error.  You can read the [`conjoint` documentation](http://keii.ue.wroc.pl/conjoint/Conjoint_R.html) for more on how to select appropriate experimental data.
(Note that the example data in the documentation always has very low numeric values, usually values between 1-10.  Compare that with your `Fee` vector, which has values up to 1000.)

You can see the source code for a function loaded into your RStudio namespace by highlighting the function name (e.g. `caFactorialDesign`) and hitting Command-Return (on a Mac - probably something similar on PC).  You can also just look at the source code on GitHub.

The `caFactorialDesign` is implemented [here](https://github.com/cran/conjoint/blob/078ada1105babb3eb511283db6c8eb8269e13ca6/R/caFactorialDesign.R#L26). That link highlights the line (26) that is throwing the error for you:

```
temp.design<-optFederov(~., data, nTrials=i, approximate=FALSE, nRepeats=50)
```

Recall the error message:

> nTrials must not be greater than the number of rows in data

You've passed in `experiment` as the `data` parameter, so `nrow(experiment)` will tell us what the upper limit on `nTrials` is:

```
nrow(experiment) # 144
```

We can actually just think of the error for this dataset as:

> nTrials must not be greater than 144

Ok, so how is the value for `nTrials` determined?  We can see `nTrials` is actually an argument to `optFederov()`, and its value is set as `i` - often a sign that there's a for-loop wrapping an operation.  And in fact, that's what we see:

```
for (i in ca.number: profiles.number)
{
   temp.design<-optFederov(~., data, nTrials=i, approximate=FALSE, nRepeats=50)
   ...
}
```

This tells us that `optFederov()` is going to get called for each value of `i` in the loop, which will start at `ca.number` and will go up to `profiles.number` (inclusive).

How are these two variables assigned?  If we look a little higher up in the `caFactorialDesign()` definition, `ca.number` is defined on lines 5-9:

```
num <- data.frame(data.matrix(data))
vars.number<-length(num)
levels.number<-0
for (i in 1:length(num)) levels.number<-levels.number+max(num[i])
ca.number<-levels.number-vars.number+1
```

You can run these calculations outside of the function - just remember that `data == experiment`.  So just change that first line to `num <- data.frame(data.matrix(experiment))`, and then run that chunk of code.  You can see that `ca.number == 1008`!!

In other words, the very first value of `i` in the for-loop which calls `optFederov()` is already way bigger than the max limit: `1008 >> 144`.

It's possible you can include these numeric values as factors or strings in your definition of `experiment` - I'm not sure if that is an appropriate way to do this analysis.  But I hope it's clear that you won't be able to use such large values in `caFactorialDesign()`, unless you have a much larger number of total observations in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your fee variable to string to avoid that error:
`Fee = c("1000","500","100")`